# Was the fast of Tisha B'av in effect during the second temple era?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, tisha-bav

As the Beis Hamikdash was rebuilt at that time was the fast of Tisha B'Av in effect during the Second Temple Era?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43922

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Mechel, and thanks for the interesting question! I hope you stick around and enjoy the rest of the site, perhaps starting with our other 100+ [tag:beis-hamikdash] questions.

Comment: @msh210 That looks like a duplicate, no?

Comment: @Scimonster, no, this whether they fasted and the other seeks an interpretation of _Z'charya_.

Comment: I felt that the question from Z'charya was more convoluted,and that this needed to be asked in a simple question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a matter of dispute between the Rishonim.

The Rambam in his commentary to the Mishna (Rosh Hashana 1, 3) wrote that the people observed the fast of Tisha b'Av even during the period of the second temple. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37942&st=&pgnum=202

However Rabbi Shimon ben Tzemach Duran (Shut Tashbetz 2, 271) wrote that they did not. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1381&pgnum=217

Apparently, this is also the view of Tosefos (Taanis 12a "Hatam") as explained by Rabbi Avraham of Minsk (Quoted In Sedeh Tzofim, see paragraph beginning 'Gemara') http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37037&st=&pgnum=179&hilite=

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick answer. I especially appreciate that you included links to the Mare Makomos, as  they would be difficult to find otherwise.

Comment: Yet, I feel that there must be more discussion regarding this in the Rishonim and Rabbinic Historians.