# Could one bring bikkurim on Tisha B'Av?

Tags: halacha-theory, tisha-bav, simchah-joy-happiness, bikkurim-first-fruits

Bikkurim can be brought from Shavuot till Sukkot and perhaps longer (not after Chanukah). Part and parcel of the mitzvah of Bikkurim seems to be an aspect of simcha/rejoicing. I have not seen any source which indicates that Bikkurim was forbidden from being brought in the (second?) temple on Tisha B'Av, which according to the prophet was still a day of fasting. Therefore I would like to know if it was in fact forbidden to bring Bikkurim in the temple on the fast day Tisha B'Av (the 9th day of Av) when simcha and rejoicing were curtailed.

Comment: why would you think of a day of mourning as an appropriate time for something which is inherently rejoicing? It's clear that to rejoice on tisha b'av is forbidden so why would this one particular action be permitted on this day?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43922/tisha-bav-fasting-in-second-temple-times

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%91) reports that there is disagreement over whether the 9th Av was a fast or simcha in the 2nd temple: יש שכתבו שקרבן העצים נקבע לט׳ באב בכוונה, לקיים את נבואת זכריה על הפיכת ימי צום לימי שמחה. לעומת זאת, הרמב"ם כותב בפירוש המשנה כי צום תשעה באב נהג גם בזמן שבית המקדש השני עמד על תילו, אך רבים חלקו על דעה זו של הרמב"ם.